# Why is my dajax-powered loading another page?

Tags: python, ajax, django

I'm working through the [random machine example](http://dajaxproject.com/random/), but I'm having trouble. I've installed Dajax and Dajaxice according to these two pages: [Dajax](https://github.com/jorgebastida/django-dajax/wiki/Installation) and [Dajaxice](http://docs.dajaxproject.com/dajaxice/installation.html). My ajax.py file looks like this:

```
import random
from dajax.core import Dajax
from dajaxice.decorators import dajaxice_register

@dajaxice_register
def randomize(request):
    dajax = Dajax()
    dajax.assign('#result','value',random.randint(1, 10))
    return dajax.json()
```

Here's my views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext

def dajax(request):
     return render_to_response( 'dajax.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request) )
```

Here's my urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url
from dajaxice.core import dajaxice_autodiscover
from dajaxice import urls
from django.conf import settings
from Dajax.myapp.views import dajax
dajaxice_autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^%s/' % (settings.DAJAXICE_MEDIA_PREFIX), include('dajaxice.urls')),
    (r'^dajax/$', dajax),
)
```

My html form tag looks like this:

```
<form>
        <input type="text" name="result" value="" id="result">
        <input type="button" name="rand" value="Let's Rand!" id="rand" onclick="Dajaxice.myapp.randomize(Dajax.process); return false;">
</form>
```

Here's what my head tag looks like:

```
<head>
    <title>My base template</title>
    {% dajaxice_js_import %}
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8"></script>
    <script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/jquery.dajax.core.js" type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8"></script>
</head>
```

I added the following to my **init**.py file in my project dir:

```
from myapp.ajax import randomize
```

Also of note, my Django app's name is myapp.

On my page, when I click on Let's Rand!, the page goes to http://localhost:8000/dajax/?result=2, and no value shows up in the text input box. I checked the console in Chromium and there aren't any errors.

Did I incorrectly install either Dajax or Dajaxice, or is there something wrong with my code above?

My guess is that because I'm using jQuery instead of Prototype, there's something different I need to do.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `return false;` in your `onClick` handler after the call to Dajax.

Comment: I changed that line to:
    <input type="button" name="rand" value="Let's Rand!" id="rand" onclick="Dajaxice.myapp.randomize(Dajax.process); return false;">, but now I get an error that says: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'randomize' of undefined"

Comment: Did you include the dajaxice generated js? Look at the html source, and open the referenced js file, does it declare the myapp object? If not, try forcing the load of the ajax.py by importing it from __init__.py or models.py. I had the problem that my ajax.py wasn't loaded sometimes, and fixed it by loading it from the __init__.py (of the app)

Comment: I found this in the dajaxice.core.js filevar Dajaxice = {
        Dajax: {
  
        myapp: {
    
            randomize: function(callback_function, argv, custom_settings){
                Dajaxice.call('Dajax.myapp.randomize', callback_function, argv, custom_settings);
            }
        }

        }.
I also tried 'from myapp import ajax' and 'from myapp.ajax import random' and neither one changed the error I'm getting.

Also, Do you know of any good tutorials that walk you through how to Dajax with jQuery? The author's website only shows example with Prototype.

Comment: I don't know any tutorials. Shouldn't you first load jquery and then the jquery dajax? (switch the script tags?). Otherwise I wouldn't know, it looks just the way I did it previously (but I don't have that code around anymore)

Comment: I tried switching the order of the script tags, and it still isn't working. Thanks for trying to help me, markijbema. I appreciate it.

Comment: no problem :) I treally looks like you're doing everything correct. Maybe you can try prepending the call to Dajaxice with 'debugger;', ando opening it in google chrome with "inspect Element" open, then when you click it pauzes the javascript and you can check whether the value of the Dajaxice object is actually set correctly. One other thing which I can think of is that you're running in debug, and even though dajaxice.core.js is created correctly, the dynamicaly generated file isn't. Did you try clicking the url in source view to see if the file served was good as well?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that the app you are trying to import the `ajak.py` file from is in your `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py`.

See the source for autodiscover:

http://docs.dajaxproject.com/dajaxice/_modules/dajaxice/core/Dajaxice.html

Answer (score 1):

put this in your views.py :

```
from dajaxice.core import dajaxice_autodiscover
dajaxice_autodiscover()
```